# How to restart transaction after abort?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have this code:

```
for foo in range(1,10):
    try:
       cur_write = self.connection.cursor()
       cur_write.execute("SELECT raise_exception(foo)")
    
       connection.commit()
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as ex:
       print "Failed to process: %s: %s", foo, ex
```

The `except` block is hit the first time correctly, but the second time around, I get:

```
psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

But the question is now, how can I "reset" the transaction, as I never really start it? I reuse the connection later in the code. Do I have to re-connect?

**Update** I solved this particular problem by taking the `commit` out of the loop, but I am still curious on how I could fix it by keeping the `commit` inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, data manipulation occurs in *transactions*. A transaction is normally started with `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and ended with `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. This is normally hidden in language adapters like `psycopg2`. And the doc says (emphasize mine):

> In Psycopg transactions are handled by the connection class. By default, **the first time a command is sent to the database (using one of the cursors created by the connection), a new transaction is created**. The following database commands will be executed in the context of the same transaction – not only the commands issued by the first cursor, but the ones issued by all the cursors created by the same connection. **Should any command fail, the transaction will be aborted and no further command will be executed until a call to the rollback() method**.

So IMHO to only reliable way is to have a `rollback` in the except branch to properly close the aborted transaction and let the next cursor operation open a clean new one:

```
for foo in range(1,10):
    try:
       cur_write = self.connection.cursor()
       cur_write.execute("SELECT raise_exception(foo)")
    
       self.connection.commit()
    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as ex:
       print "Failed to process: %s: %s", foo, ex
       self.connection.rollback()             # cleanup the aborted transaction
```

Comment: Could I put in a `commit()` to create a "rollback point" ?